# Remove rows in pandas df with index values within a range

Tags: pandas

I would like to remove all rows in a pandas df that have an index value within 4 counts of the index value of the previous row.

In the pandas df below,

```
    A   B  
0   1   1  
5   5   5  
8   9   9  
9   10  10
```

Only the row with index value 0 should remain.

Thanks!

Comment: 0 to 5 is count as 5..

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: What @YOBEN_S means is that your logic is wrong, 0 + 4 is 4 not 5

Comment: Yes, true. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This can be done quite easily by: `df[df.index.isin(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.min()+4))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the differences between the current and previous row as a list and pass to `loc`. Chose to get it as a list so i could return a dataframe as a final output.

```
ind = [ a for a,b in zip(df.index,df.index[1:]) if b-a > 4]
df.loc[ind]

    A   B
0   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reset_index`, `diff` and `shift`:

```
In [1309]: df 
Out[1309]: 
    A   B
0   1   1
5   5   5
8   9   9
9  10  10

In [1310]: d = df.reset_index()

In [1313]: df = d[d['index'].diff(1).shift(-1) >=4].drop('index', 1) 
In [1314]: df
Out[1313]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
```